# Accessing Old Seagate HDD Model ST4350N

Tags: hard-disk, scsi

I have an Old HDD Seagate Model ST4350N. I want to access the data on the Hard disk. 
[image: Seaget ST4350N]
The Hard disk have 50 pin connector
[image: Hard Disk Interface]
I am hoping for guidance on how to even begin the process. What kind of controller and equipment do i need for reading the drive.

Comment: Quick googling [finds](https://stason.org/TULARC/pc/hard-drives-hdd/seagate/ST4350N-WREN-300MB-5-25-FH-SCSI1-SE.html) that the interface is SCSI 1. So you need a SCSI 1 controller, or some way to emulate one on modern hardware (e.g. some embedded controller), if such a thing exists. Pinout is [here](http://old.pinouts.ru/HD/ScsiExternalCentronics50_pinout.shtml) (single ended).

Comment: Adaptec used to produce an interface called "USB2XChange", an SCSI controller on a USB cable (no longer made, unfortunately) - It might be worth looking out for such an adapter on the second-hand market

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a SCSI device, so it shouldn’t be too hard to get the data off the device. You need the following pieces of equipment:

- a SCSI controller, known as a host bus adapter (HBA); these are available for most buses, including USB (getting rare though), PCI and PCI Express (the last two are still easy enough to find, especially second-hand; expect to pay a premium for new controllers);
- a SCSI cable, with appropriate connectors (we’ll get to that);
- depending on the cable, perhaps an adapter;
- depending on the cable and the drive specifics, perhaps a terminator (although since this would be the only drive on the bus, you should be able to get away without one).

The simplest option would be to find a computer with a PCI (not PCI Express) slot, and install a PCI SCSI HBA. Most of those still have 50-pin SCSI SE ports; you can then use a 50-pin internal SCSI cable to connect the drive directly. Set the jumpers for drive-provided termination (see [the settings here](https://stason.org/TULARC/pc/hard-drives-hdd/seagate/ST4350N-WREN-300MB-5-25-FH-SCSI1-SE.html)), and it should “just work”.

If it doesn’t work, the drive might be a bit too old and not support the identification protocol. In that case, you’ll need to find an older HBA which doesn’t care too much about this; I have an old Adaptec 2940 for exactly this kind of situation.

If you don’t have a system with old PCI connectors, but with PCI Express connectors, then you’ll only find HBAs with Ultra320 buses and 68-pin connectors. In that case, you’ll need a 68-pin internal cable; these include terminators in most cases, but again that shouldn’t cause problems if you have a short cable and only one drive on the bus. You’ll also need a 68- to 50-pin female-to-female adapter such as [this one](http://www.scsi4me.com/int-hd50f-hd68f.html). Set the drive jumpers for bus-powered termination.

Once all that’s done, a Linux setup should see the drive immediately; on Windows, you’ll need to install the drivers for the HBA, but if it’s old enough (and most of them are) there’s a decent chance the drivers will be built in. I’m not sure about macOS.

There are other possibilities, *e.g.* placing the drive in an external enclosure and connecting that to the SCSI HBA; that opens even more possibilities for mis-matched cables and terminators. The above should get you going though...

Comment: If I would have to guess about MacOS, it should also see the drive immediately, like Linux does. Can't say for sure though...

Comment: Thank You for your guidance, Stephen. I was able to access the Hard drive.